# Получение массива из multiselect для суммирования и вычитания data-*

Tags: javascript, jquery

Пытаюсь собрать  элементы, которые у меня есть в data-* и посчитать сумму выбранных в multiselet. Нужно добавление и удаление в массива на multiselect,однако по идее мой код

https://gist.github.com/vasilukwolf/1a431069ffa40531e96b1375d553dd5a

Должен добавлять элементы до бесконечности.Однако он добавляет лишь один элемент. Мне нужно собрать массив данных выбранных пользователем.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
// Заполнение window.accessories
//...
accessorieTaxm = {};

$(document).ready(function() {
    //...

    $('select#tax_accessorie').change(function() {
        var strollersModel = $(this).val();
        var selectedOption = this.options[this.selectedIndex];
        var id = selectedOption.getAttribute("data-id").toString();
        var value = accessorieTaxm[id] || false;
        accessorieTaxm[id] = !value;
    });

    //...
});


function sum() {
    //...

    var sumPrice = 0;

    for (key in accessorieTaxm) {
        if (accessorieTaxm[key]) {
            sumPrice += window.accessories[key].price;
        }
    }

    //...
}
```